# HowTo Resize DataGrid Columns Width Based On Window Width in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following DataGrid where I want the column sizes to be automatically stretched so that the full window size is used with all existing columns. Actually the widths of my five columns are minimum sized. This means I have a window size of 640 pixes where the five columns fill 360 pixels.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPerson" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonObject}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Facebook" Binding="{Binding Facebook}" />
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Button Click="btnEditPerson_Click">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12"
                                               Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_refresh}" />
                                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                                    </Rectangle>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button Click="btnDeletePerson_Click">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12"
                                               Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_delete}" />
                                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                                    </Rectangle>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Button>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Width on all DataGridTextColumn's to "*"

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="*" ... />
```

This is a relative size, if all columns are set to *, then they will all be of equal size relative to the parent window.

You can go one step further by prefixing the * with a number, such as:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" ... />
<DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" ... />
```

In this case, the second column will take up twice the amount of space as the first column.

Comment: Exactly what I have searched for. Solved my issue. Thanks.